# Why mysql_real_escape_string not work on MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

Why `mysql_real_escape_string` not work on MySQLi ?

When i use MySQL , i can use this code.

```
$test = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[test]);
```

But When i update to use MySQLi. I tried to use

```
$test = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[test]);
```

But not work.

How can i use `mysql_real_escape_string` on `MySQLi` ?

if cannot use `mysql_real_escape_string` on `MySQLi` , How can i protect SQL Injection ?

Now i use

```
$test = $_POST[test];
```

It's very bad for SQL Injection.

Comment: You use `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead now

Comment: can i use `$db_mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST[test]);` ?

Comment: Use parameterized queries. They are much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can i use `mysql_real_escape_string` on `MySQLi`?

**Answer:**

OOP Approach:
`$test = $conn -> real_escape_string($_POST['test']);`

Procedural Approach: `$test = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['test']);`

**You are also asking on how can you protect from SQL Injection**

**Answer:** If you are going to use `mysqli_*` then you should use `parameterized queries`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php